# angular ui bootstrap window templateurl not working

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

I have tried the code in http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal.
The windowTemplateUrl does not embed the data in templateUrl.Here is my plunk: https://plnkr.co/edit/6zM6VXDPjvl3yRewkNsV?p=preview

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo">
  <head>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.9/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="//angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="example.js"></script>
    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="ModalDemoCtrl">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open()">Open me!</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('lg')">Large modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open('sm')">Small modal</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="toggleAnimation()">Toggle Animation ({{ animationsEnabled }})</button>
    <div ng-show="selected">Selection from a modal: {{ selected }}</div>
</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  $scope.open = function (size) {

        var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
          animation: $scope.animationsEnabled,
          templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
          windowTemplateUrl: 'custom.html',
          controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
          size: size,
          resolve: {
            items: function () {
              return $scope.items;
            }
          }
        });

        modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
          $scope.selected = selectedItem;
        }, function () {
          $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
        });
      };
```

update your `custom.html`

```
<div class="modal" id="myModal" ng-style="{'z-index': 1050 + index*10, display: 'block'}">
    <div class="modal-dialog Signcl" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Sign Up</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" ng-transclude>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Continue</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I need to override the modals window template to the new one.

Comment: @Nishaharidas you try `modalTemplateUrl: 'custom.html',` for change the default template

Comment: Can you at least describe the solution not just posting the code? what happened? why didnt it work for him and what was the solution?